# Reorganizing a picklist based on aisle direction

Tags: sql, sorting, cursor, common-table-expression, picklist

So I will explain the entire problem first, then explain where the problem is in SQL coding for me.

I have a set of data that is a picklist through a warehouse, I am essentially trying to reorganize this data to follow a one direction in each aisle.

so for example, here is a picklist

> tripid  stopseq   AISLE   bin
>
> 216   1   PV  71
>
> 216    2   PM  64
>
> 216    3   PL  47
>
> 216    4   PM  36
>
> 216    5   PL  32
>
> 216    6   PL  88
>
> 216    7   PJ  49
>
> 216    8   PJ  29
>
> 216    9   PJ  20
>
> 216    10  PJ  19
>
> 216    11  PI  22
>
> 216    12  PI  45
>
> 216    13  PN  33
>
> 216    14  PN  28

since aisles can only go one way, some are ascending and some are descending

in this case, I want to reorganize this table so that aisle PJ is ascending(picks 7,8,9,10)
so I would like it to go through the picklist and reorder the picksequence based on the aisles being ascending or descending. I will only focus on one aisle for this example, So im looking for a query that will loop through the table, and reorganize records with column PJ so that is goes in the opposite order. similar to

> 216 7  PJ 19
>
> 216 8  PJ 20
>
> 216 9  PJ  29
>
> 216 10  PJ  49

but I am only trying to affect those rows right now.
So far I have created a cursor, with a CTE inside of it. Something like this.

```
declare inner_cursor cursor scroll
for select aisle from table_input

open inner_cursor

fetch next from inner_cursor into @aisle
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    if @aisle in ('PJ')
    begin 
      with C as
            (select stopseq, 0 + row_number() over (order by bin desc) as newtripstop
            from SIM_Input_reschedule
            )
            update C 
            set tripstopseq = newtripstop
        end
```

but that will only order the whole list by the Bin number, so I tried to add a constraint for aisle
by adding

```
begin
            with C as
            (select tripstopseq, 0 + row_number() over (order by bin asc) as newtripstop, aisle
            from SIM_Input_reschedule
            where AISLE = @aisle
            )
            update C 
            set tripstopseq = newtripstop
        end
```

but that affected no rows in the table. Any help is appreciated. I might have been taking an entirely wrong approach to this with the CTE, so just say if you think of a better way to do it.

Comment: does the CTE select give you the required values in newtripstop field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you can do is this.

Add field `sort_order` which will only have two values:

- 1 - for aisles that should be sorted in ascending order
- (-1) - for aisles with desc sort order

Then you can use following query to results in correct sort order:

```
SELECT aisle, bin, 
  ( SELECT MAX(sequence) FROM myTable 
    WHERE t.aisle != aisle and sequence < t.sequence)
  + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY aisle ORDER BY sort_order * bin) as newsequence
FROM myTable t
```

To do this without the new field you will have to use CASE WHEN with same logic.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to order by aisle. I want to keep the rest of the order the exact same in the list. I want to replace the actual stopseq field in the table. I still want it to go 1-10 in stopseq, just reorder only the rows with PJ. This does organize it how I would like the row to go end result, but not what I am looking for.